# How do i structure my Python submodule with a lot of files, so that i have to import only one module

Tags: python, module

I have a Python Project named `osinttool` which contains a folder named `osinttool` which contains the .py-files.
In this folder, I have a folder named database that contains a file named db.py and there are several functions for creating entries in my database, deleting them and so on. In my other files, I just import like that `'from database import db'` and that works fine.

The problem is, there is such a lot of code in db.py and I want to split up the code so that every different resource has its own file, but I still want to only import one module to use all of these databases function. It would be super nice if I don't even have to change anything in the files that use the DB-module.

How could I do that?

Comment: You could convert `db` into a package, using an `__init__.py` file to provide access to the functions within the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend converting `db` into a package in itself, with a directory structure like below, including an `__init__.py` file which provides the package's public API.

```
- db
    - __init__.py
    - dbtools.py
```

Suppose you have a module `dbtools.py` inside your `db` package, which defines a function `initialize_db_connection`. You could then create an `__init__.py` file at the same level with contents like:

```
from .dbtools import initialize_db_connection
```

You could then import this as `from db import initialize_db_connection`, even though the function is within a module in the package.

In the modules which already import as `from database import db`, your function would be accessible as `db.initialize_db_connection`.

Comment: s/script/module/g